# In parse object.save(); doesnt return anything why?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Here is my code, it loops through forEach and prints out '1' but never returns from object.save() & never prints out 2, 3 or anything else. I have tried a bunch of other ways but none seems to work.

Note: response.succes(or error) is not being called anywhere, the code is definitely waiting for object.save() to be completed.

```
var promise = new Parse.Promise();

var query = new Parse.Query("SomeClass");
query.find().then(function(results) {
    var promises = [];

    results.forEach(function(object) {
        object.set("SomeColumnName", true);
        console.log('1');

        promises.push(object.save(null, {
            success: function(result) {
                alert('2');                   
                return ;
            },
            error: function(result, error) {
                alert('3');
                return ;
            }
        }));
    });

    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        console.log('inside resolve');
        promise.resolve();
    }, function() {
        console.log('inside reject');
        promise.reject();
    });
});

return promise;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you should take advantage of the fact that most of the sdk functions create and return promises for you.  With those, you can substantially simplify the code:

```
// very handy utility library that provides _.each among many other things
// www.underscorejs.org
var _ = require('underscore');

// answer a promise to modify all instances of SomeClass
function changeSomeClass() {
    var query = new Parse.Query("SomeClass");
    // if there are more than 100 rows, set query.limit up to 1k
    return query.find().then(function(results) {  // find returns a promise
        _.each(results, function(result) {
            result.set("SomeColumnName", true);
        });
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(results);  // and saveAll returns a promise
    });
}
```

Wrap it in a cloud function and call success/error like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("changeSomeClass", function(request, response) {
    changeSomeClass().then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one Parse request happening at a time for each object.  If multiple requests are sent, all but the first are ignored.  You're probably trying to do this while other threads are making Parse requests for those objects.  I know that if you save an object, it also saves it's child objects, so you could be hitting a problem with that.  Make sure you do as much as you can in background threads with completion blocks, or use saveEventually / fetchEventually where possible.

Comment: Do you mean that object.save() is not async and isn't already on another thread? I believe this is cloud code too.